# Отображение прогресса на иконке приложения в панели задач

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gui, vista

Можно ли как-то сделать для своего приложения так, чтобы прогресс отображался на иконке приложения в панели задач?

Например, так: [image: Экранный снимок прогресса на панели задач]

Comment: Пример и пояснения [здесь](http://nicug.blogspot.ru/2011/01/windows-7-taskbar-extensions-in-qt.html) (да ещё и бонусом - оверлейная иконка). **UPD** А если интересует не только Windows 7+, то можно посмотреть на библиотеку [QtDockTile](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135443/).